# My implementation of adding elements to a linked list has a logic error

Tags: c++

Essentially, I have an assignment from my professor that involves using linked lists in c++. I must create a program in which I input a string and pass it to a function that will return a head pointer for a linked list. The linked list holds nodes that contain a char value for a letter, an integer value for the number of occurrences, and a pointer to another node.

```
struct sortedListNode {
char letter;
int occurence;
sortedListNode* next;
};
```

This is the struct definition for each node. Below is a function that passes in a string, creates a node for each unique letter, holds the number of occurrences of each letter in the string, and sorts the values in alphabetical order. Assume all lower case letters. (using standard namespace btw). It returns the head pointer of the linked list.

```
sortedListNode* fromString(string word) {
sortedListNode* head = new sortedListNode{};
sortedListNode* currentPos = new sortedListNode{};
sortedListNode* predPos = new sortedListNode{};
bool found;
bool placed;
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    //set currentPos back to the head pointer to traverse list again
    currentPos = head->next;
    predPos = head;


    //check if letter is in linked list 
    found = false;
    while (currentPos != NULL) {
        if (currentPos->letter == word[i]) {
            currentPos->occurence += 1;
            found = true;
        }
        currentPos = currentPos->next;
    }
    currentPos = head->next;
    //

    //if not, add it
    if (found == false) {

        // if list is empty
        if (head->next == NULL) {
            sortedListNode* item = new sortedListNode{};
            item->letter = word[i];
            item->occurence = 1;
            item->next = NULL;
            head->next = item;
        }
        // if item is smaller than first element
        else if (word.at(i) < head->next->letter) {
            sortedListNode* item = new sortedListNode{};
            item->letter = word[i];
            item->occurence = 1;
            item->next = head->next;
            head->next = item;
        }
        // if item is in the middle/end
        else {
            placed = false;
            // create node
            sortedListNode* item = new sortedListNode{};
            item->letter = word[i];
            item->occurence = 1;

            // iterate position
            while (currentPos != NULL)
            {
                if (currentPos->letter > item->letter && item->letter > predPos->letter)
                {
                    item->next = currentPos;
                    predPos->next = item;
                    placed = true;
                    break;
                }
                currentPos = currentPos->next;
            }
            if (placed == false && currentPos == NULL)
            {
                item->next = NULL;
                predPos->next = item;
            }
        }


    }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Apologies, it wouldn't indent properly when copy pasted. Finally, I have a subroutine that passes in a sortedListNode pointer and will iterate through the linked list, printing out each of the unique characters and their occurrences in alphabetical order.

```
void printList(sortedListNode* node) {
    sortedListNode* currentPos = node->next;
    while (currentPos != NULL) {
        cout << currentPos->letter << " : " << currentPos->occurence << "\t";
        currentPos = currentPos->next;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

In this program I have tested many string values to pass into a fromString(). I noticed a logic error occurring. I seemed to isolate the problem but can't fix it. When entering in a string such as "abcdef"

```
sortedListNode* list1;
list1 = fromString("abcdef");
printList(list1);
```

The output is

> f : 1

However, inputting a string such as "fedcba" gives a different result

```
sortedListNode* list2;
list2 = fromString("fedcba");
printList(list2);
```

The output is

> a : 1  b : 1  c : 1  d : 1  e : 1  f : 1

which is correct.

I understand that my issue is in sorting. However, I haven't been able to fix this. If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated.

I apologize for sloppy code writing techniques, I am still a student. Please don't judge too harshly for my inexperience.

Comment: Since you have identified both a working and not-working case, you should be able to explore around that.  For instance, what if you just have two characters?  It looks like if you provide them in reverse-sorted order, it works, but in sorted order you end up breaking your list such that the last item is at the head.  With only two list nodes, you should be able to easily step through your program's execution in a debugger, line by line, and discover the problem.

Comment: @paddy Although I may have isolated the problem, and even possibly found the faulty piece of code. I am unable to find a solution. I believe the problem arises at the section of  fromString(string word) under the comment // if the item is in the middle/end

Comment: @paddy nevermind, I found it. forgot to update predPos after each iteration of a while loop.

Comment: Correct, that is the most likely place to start looking.  Step through in your debugger, and/or add output statements to your loop to verify assumptions about important values (such as pointers).  Or imagine your list contains a single node and you're adding a new one, and walk through that function by hand to identify where your logic is wrong.

Comment: Ah, okay very good.  Try to apply an investigative approach to your program when you don't know what's wrong.  Start breaking it down into the simplest case, and work it out.  This is an utterly crucial skill to develop as a programmer, and the better you are at doing it, the more employable you will be.  It's fine to ask for help, but you should first follow through with what you know.